# Spark SQL explain plan calls the temporary table calculation many times

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark SQL, and use explain to learn how it can optimize code. I had assumed a table defined in WITH and referred by many times is calculated only once.

However based on optimized logical plan of the following explain, the table location_with_count appears in different trees.

Does it mean it will be calculated twice or this is only a display issue of a plan explanation.

```py
In [24]: sql = """
    ...:     WITH location_with_count AS (
    ...:         SELECT uid, country_code, city_code, count() over (PARTITION BY country_code, city_code) as c
    ...:         FROM location
    ...:     ),
    ...:
    ...:     rs AS (
    ...:         SELECT uid, country_code, city_code,
    ...:           row_number() over (PARTITION BY country_code, city_code
    ...:                              ORDER BY uid DESC) AS Rank
    ...:         FROM location_with_count as uc
    ...:         WHERE uc.c > 10
    ...:     )
    ...:
    ...:     (SELECT uid, country_code, city_code FROM rs WHERE Rank <= 10)
    ...:     union
    ...:     (SELECT uid, country_code, city_code FROM location_with_count WHERE c <= 10)
    ...:     """

In [25]: session.sql(sql).explain(True)
```

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
CTE [location_with_count, rs]
:  :- 'SubqueryAlias location_with_count
:  :  +- 'Project ['uid, 'country_code, 'city_code, 'count() windowspecdefinition('country_code, 'city_code, UnspecifiedFrame) AS c#281]
:  :     +- 'UnresolvedRelation `location`
:  +- 'SubqueryAlias rs
:     +- 'Project ['uid, 'country_code, 'city_code, 'row_number() windowspecdefinition('country_code, 'city_code, 'uid DESC NULLS LAST, UnspecifiedFrame) AS Rank#282]
:        +- 'Filter ('uc.c > 10)
:           +- 'SubqueryAlias uc
:              +- 'UnresolvedRelation `location_with_count`
+- 'Distinct
+- 'Union
:- 'Project ['uid, 'country_code, 'city_code]
:  +- 'Filter ('Rank <= 10)
:     +- 'UnresolvedRelation `rs`
+- 'Project ['uid, 'country_code, 'city_code]
+- 'Filter ('c <= 10)
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `location_with_count`
== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
uid: bigint, country_code: string, city_code: string
Distinct
+- Union
:- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:  +- Filter (Rank#282 <= 10)
:     +- SubqueryAlias rs
:        +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287, Rank#282]
:           +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287, Rank#282, Rank#282]
:              +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(country_code#284, city_code#287, uid#283L DESC NULLS LAST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Rank#282], [country_code#284, city_code#287], [uid#283L DESC NULLS LAST]
:                 +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:                    +- Filter (c#281L > cast(10 as bigint))
:                       +- SubqueryAlias uc
:                          +- SubqueryAlias location_with_count
:                             +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287, c#281L]
:                                +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287, c#281L, c#281L]
:                                   +- Window [count() windowspecdefinition(country_code#284, city_code#287, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS c#281L], [country_code#284, city_code#287]
:                                      +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:                                         +- SubqueryAlias location
:                                            +- Relation[uid#283L,country_code#284,city_code#287] parquet
+- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- Filter (c#281L <= cast(10 as bigint))
+- SubqueryAlias location_with_count
+- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287, c#281L]
+- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287, c#281L, c#281L]
+- Window [count() windowspecdefinition(country_code#284, city_code#287, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS c#281L], [country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- SubqueryAlias location
                           +- Relation[uid#283L,country_code#284,city_code#287] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287], [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- Union
:- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:  +- Filter (isnotnull(Rank#282) && (Rank#282 <= 10))
:     +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(country_code#284, city_code#287, uid#283L DESC NULLS LAST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Rank#282], [country_code#284, city_code#287], [uid#283L DESC NULLS LAST]
:        +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:           +- Filter (c#281L > 10)
:              +- Window [0 AS c#281L], [country_code#284, city_code#287]
:                 +- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:                    +- Relation[uid#283L,country_code#284,city_code#287] parquet
+- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- Filter (c#281L <= 10)
+- Window [0 AS c#281L], [country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- Relation[uid#283L,country_code#284,city_code#287] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287], functions=[], output=[uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287, 200)
+- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287], functions=[], output=[uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287])
+- Union
:- *Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:  +- *Filter (isnotnull(Rank#282) && (Rank#282 <= 10))
:     +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(country_code#284, city_code#287, uid#283L DESC NULLS LAST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Rank#282], [country_code#284, city_code#287], [uid#283L DESC NULLS LAST]
:        +- *Sort [country_code#284 ASC NULLS FIRST, city_code#287 ASC NULLS FIRST, uid#283L DESC NULLS LAST], false, 0
:           +- *Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:              +- *Filter (c#281L > 10)
:                 +- Window [0 AS c#281L], [country_code#284, city_code#287]
:                    +- *Sort [country_code#284 ASC NULLS FIRST, city_code#287 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:                       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(country_code#284, city_code#287, 200)
:                          +- *Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
:                             +- *FileScan parquet default.location[uid#283L,country_code#284,city_code#287] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[.../location], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<uid:bigint,country_code:string,city_code:string>
+- *Project [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- *Filter (c#281L <= 10)
+- Window [0 AS c#281L], [country_code#284, city_code#287]
+- *Sort [country_code#284 ASC NULLS FIRST, city_code#287 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                     +- ReusedExchange [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287], Exchange hashpartitioning(country_code#284, city_code#287, 200)
```

In the physical plan, I see

```
ReusedExchange [uid#283L, country_code#284, city_code#287], Exchange hashpartitioning(country_code#284, city_code#287, 200)
```

Does it actually indicate location_with_count is reused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubqueryAlias` logical operator will eventually be eliminated by the `EliminateSubqueryAliases` logical optimization. Aliases are pointers (references) to the same parts of a query and does not participate in execution.

You may find a bit information in [EliminateSubqueryAliases Logical Optimization](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Optimizer-EliminateSubqueryAliases.html).

There is the `ReuseSubquery` physical query optimization that should avoid executing subqueries multiple times.

You can find a bit information in [ReuseSubquery Physical Query Optimization](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-ReuseSubquery.html).

> Does it actually indicate location_with_count is reused?

I'd expect so.

Comment: The site https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql also looks very interesting. In general does Spark have a way to print out all the optimizations applied to a query in sequence and the logical or physical plan before and after each optimization?

Comment: Yes. But you're going to be overwhelmed very quickly. See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-catalyst-RuleExecutor.html for a bit on it which boils down to turn TRACE on.